# Running lines from an external text file

Tags: c++, file-io, ifstream

I have a program that takes lines of user input using `cin.getline()`

I have a cin.getline(inputString, MAX_LENGTH) where the user would enter a list of valid commands such as

```
add -user "CoolGuy22" "John"
```

I parse inputString and it adds the users and such.
Now I am trying to create a way to run a bunch of commands from an exterior file. Each line on the exterior text file is a different command to test for the user input commands. Such as

```
add -user "CoolGuy22" "John"
add -user "CoolGirl22" "Jenny"
add -delete "CoolGuy22" "John"
```

Here is the command for I run. It asks for a user input.

```
void Display::getInput(){
  SessionLog log;
  StringEval eval;
  cout << endl << endl << "Enter Command: ";
  char input[MAX_LENGTH];
  //string input;
  cin.getline(input, MAX_LENGTH);
  eval.parseString(input);

  getInput();
```

> I will type in `.read "script.text"`

This should read the script.text file and input individual commands from the script to automate the testing.

```
if (inputString.substr(0, 5) == ".read"){
  cout << "Read from file: \"" << inputString.substr(6, inputString.length()-6) << "\"" << endl;
  ifstream inFile;
  inFile.open(inputString.substr(6, inputString.length()-6));
  if (!inFile) {
    cerr << "Unable to open file script.txt" << endl;
    //GOTTA READ THE LINES NOW
  }
```

I successfully access script.txt, but now I am stuck. I'm not sure how to have each individual line on the script.text to be sent to back to the program. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: actually I am not sure if I completely misunderstood the question... what `cin.getline` do you mean?

Comment: @tobi303 I edited the main post, hopefully that clears up what I'm trying to do. Thanks!

Comment: ok, a bit more clear. Indeed it was my misunderstanding. However, there is still no `cin.getline` in the code

Comment: @tobi303 inputString.substr(0, 5) is a part of the cin.getline() function mentioned in the main post. This code where the program reads the file is after the .read "script.text" file

Comment: `getline` is a function from the standard lib, how can your line of code be part of it? Please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read the file line by line, just do this:

```
std::ifstream inFile(<path>);
if (!inFile.is_open()) {
    exit(1); // Handle error
}

std::string line;
while(std::getline(inFile, line)) {
    std::cout << line << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: The problem with this is that it simply outputs to the console instead of turning it into input for the program.

Comment: @user1692517, you'll have to be more specific. What do you mean by 'input for the program'? Do you want to execute these commands through the shell?